# Inserting data from excel sheet into sql temp table

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I have created the following temp table in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
CREATE TABLE ##LoginMap
(
    ObjectId NVARCHAR(50), 
    UserPrincipleName NVARCHAR(500), 
    Username NVARCHAR(250),
    Email NVARCHAR(500), 
    Name NVARCHAR(250)
)
```

These are the same names as the column headers in the excel sheet I am trying to get the data from.

The file name is called `Test Loadsheet` and the sheet name is `AgilityExport_04Aug2022_164839`.

I am trying to insert the data into the temp table like so:

```
INSERT INTO ##LoginMap
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\temp\Test LoadSheet.xlsx', [AgilityExport_04Aug2022_164839]);
GO
```

However, I am getting the error:

> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "AgilityExport_04Aug2022_164839". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Where have I gone wrong with this? And what do I need to do in order to successfully get the data from each column into my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went about this a different way. In the excel sheet I am using a made a formula like so:

```
="INSERT INTO ##LoginMap(ObjectId, DisplayName, AzureEmail, AzureUsername) VALUES('"&A2&"', '"&B2&"', '"&C2&"',  '"&D2&"');"
```

I then had this repeated for each row. This then gave me an insert statement for each that I could simply copy and paste into SSMS and allow to run the query

Answer (score 1):

You have file name as Test Loadsheet in one spot, but then in your query you have it as Test LoadSheet.xlsx. Try and see if this is holding it up.

Found a link on importing data from excel to SQL if you are interested:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#openrowset